# Spring - Is it possible to map multiple fields to a single form error?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, user-interface

I have the first name and last name fields in a form, but I want to use the same div to display any of their errors.

Form Fields:

```
<form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" cssErrorClass="errorStyle"/>
<form:input path="firstName" id="firstName" cssErrorClass="errorStyle"/>
```

I would like to be able to bind the form:errors to multiple paths such as below:

```
<form:errors path="firstName, lastName" element="div"/>
```

Is this possible?
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<form:errors path="*" element="div" cssClass="error-message"/>
```

---

One option may be to invest the words so

```
     nameFirst = firstName 

     nameLast = lastName
```

and then use

```
<form:errors path="name*" element="div" cssClass="error-message"/>
```

Reference : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html

Comment: But that way, all the errors in the form will be displayed there, which is not what I want as I have other fields in the form. I only want the errors from those particular fields to be displayed in that div.

Comment: @shanti Proof this new option